# Where Clause Error Eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent

I wanna ask why I'm getting an error of

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$user_id`

Here's my code

```
if(!empty($parents)){
    $transactions = $this->loadupPayment
    ->select('*')
    ->where('user_id', $parents->user_id)
    ->orderby('reference_date', 'DESC')
    ->get();
}
```

here's the query of `$parents`

```
    $parents = false;
    if(!empty(array_filter($request->getParams())))
    {
        $parents = $this->user
        ->leftjoin('sys_user_parent', 'sys_user_parent.user_id', '=', 'sys_user.user_id')
        ->select('*')
        ->where(function($query) use ($request) {

            $first_name = $request->getParam('first_name');
            $last_name  = $request->getParam('last_name');
            $id_no = $request->getParam('parent_no');
            $child_name = $request->getParam('child_name');

            if ($first_name != '') {
                $query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%'. $first_name .'%');
            }

            if ($last_name != '') {
                $query->where('last_name', 'LIKE', '%'. $last_name .'%');
            }

            if ($id_no != '') {
                $query->where('identification_number', 'LIKE', '%'. $id_no .'%');
            }

        })
        ->where('user_type_id', '3')            
        ->get();
```

Comment: Have you checked this `$parents`? what you are getting `dd($parents)`

Comment: what do you mean `dd($parents)` sir? sorry

Comment: before this query just put dd($parents); and put the output here

Comment: yes try that what you are getting? And what is `loadupPayment`? is that a function?

Comment: It seems that `$parents` is a collection instead of a instance of a model

Comment: in `$parents` it is selecting data in a table

Comment: in `dd($parents)` i'm getting the the data i needed to select data in `$transactions`

Comment: can you provide the query on the `$parents` variable?

Comment: @elegisandi, there. I've edited my post, thank you

Comment: ahh, you should use this on your transactions query: `->whereIn('user_id', $parents->pluck('user_id')->all())`

Comment: @elegisandi , it does'nt display anything

Comment: Ahh try toArra()y instead of all()